# Firebase UI Email Link opens app and is handled by the proper method, but does not sign in the user

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

- iOS target: 12.2
- Language: Swift
- Firebase SDK version: 6.3.0
- Firebase UI version: 8.1.0
- Firebase Dynamic Links version: 4.0.5
- Device: iPad Air running iOS 12.4.2

I am currently running into the issue using FirebaseUI on iOS (swift) where when I try to handle an email link, it will not sign the user in.

I have the user use the FirebaseUI email link flow, which successfully sends an email to their email. When I open the link from the email it opens through the method

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    print(self.TAG, "GOT TO RESTORATION HANDLER!", userActivity, userActivity.webpageURL)
    guard let webUrl = userActivity.webpageURL else {
        return false
    }
    let handled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(webUrl) { (link, err) in
        print(self.TAG, "HANDLING UNIVERSAL LINK!", link, err)
    self.handlePasswordlessSignIn(with: link?.url)
    }
    return handled
}
```

This is done in accordance to Step 6. from https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#open-dynamic-links-in-your-app

I then try to handle the sign in like so:

```swift
if let link = link, let auth = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI(), let del = delegate {
    let actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings()
        actionCodeSettings.url = URL(string: websiteContinueURL )
    actionCodeSettings.handleCodeInApp = true
    actionCodeSettings.setIOSBundleID(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
    actionCodeSettings.setAndroidPackageName(bundleIdentifier, installIfNotAvailable: true, minimumVersion: "12")
    let provider = FUIEmailAuth(authAuthUI: auth, signInMethod: EmailLinkAuthSignInMethod, forceSameDevice: true, allowNewEmailAccounts: true, actionCodeSetting: actionCodeSettings)

    auth.providers = [provider, FUIGoogleAuth(), FUIFacebookAuth()]
    print(self.TAG, "TRYING TO SIGN IN EMAIL LINK!!!")

    if auth.handleOpen(link, sourceApplication: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!) {
        // if it handled it, which it does, I callback from here
        // but the auth state at this point, or at any other point after this,
        // even after the "signed in" modal, is unchanged
    }
}
```

Which then provides a modal popup saying "Signed In!" but the auth state of the user does not change. I use that method to handle the URL specifically because 
a) due to using FirebaseUI I do not have access to the user's email that they use to sign up with until they are signed in 
and b) it is the method I am told to use via the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#email_link_authentication (this says Auth.defaultAuthUI, but it should be FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI(), Auth has no property/method defaultAuthUI, since that is a FirebaseUI component)

I have tried the following:

- In the application method where the link is sent to when the app opens, I have tried sending the original userActivity.webpageURL. Does not work.
- I have tried signing out the user prior to this so that there is no existing user before the url is handled. Does not work.
- Trying to capture the url in other application methods, which does not work as it is only ever sent to that method with the restoration handler.

This **only** is occurring on iOS, as I am able to finish the same flow in android without issue every single time. I also have not been able to replicate this in its own project as the email link verification appears to require that the app be deployed to the app store, as an earlier issue I was having was that the dynamic link would not open the app whatsoever. However, once that issue was resolved, this one popped up.

Note: I have gone and traced the sign in method into the code I CAN see, and the sourceApplication field appears to not matter whatsoever, so even though I am using the bundle identifier, the method it is received in never makes use of it. Just to confirm:

FUIAuth.m

```c
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)URL
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication {
  // Complete IDP-based sign-in flow.
  for (id<FUIAuthProvider> provider in _providers) {
    if ([provider handleOpenURL:URL sourceApplication:sourceApplication]) {
      return YES;
    }
  }
  // The URL was not meant for us.
  return NO;
}
```

FUIEmailAuth.m (the class this is implemented in extends the FUIAuthProvider protocol)

```c
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)URL sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication {
  self.emailLink = URL.absoluteString;

  // Retrieve continueUrl from URL
  NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:URL.absoluteString];
  NSString *continueURLString;
  for (NSURLQueryItem *queryItem in urlComponents.queryItems) {
    if ([queryItem.name isEqualToString:@"continueUrl"]) {
      continueURLString = queryItem.value;
    }
  }
  if (!continueURLString) {
    NSLog(@"FUIEmailAuth unable to handle url without continue URL: %@", URL);
    return NO;
  }

  // Retrieve url parameters from continueUrl
  NSMutableDictionary *urlParameterDict= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  NSURLComponents *continueURLComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:continueURLString];
  for (NSURLQueryItem *queryItem in continueURLComponents.queryItems) {
    urlParameterDict[queryItem.name] = queryItem.value;
  }
  // Retrieve parameters from local storage
  NSMutableDictionary *localParameterDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  localParameterDict[kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey] = [GULUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults
                                                  stringForKey:kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey];
  localParameterDict[@"ui_sid"] = [GULUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults stringForKey:@"ui_sid"];

  // Handling flows
  NSString *urlSessionID = urlParameterDict[@"ui_sid"];
  NSString *localSessionID = localParameterDict[@"ui_sid"];
  BOOL sameDevice = urlSessionID && localSessionID && [urlSessionID isEqualToString:localSessionID];

  if (sameDevice) {
    // Same device
    if (urlParameterDict[@"ui_pid"]) {
      // Unverified provider linking
      [self handleUnverifiedProviderLinking:urlParameterDict[@"ui_pid"]
                                      email:localParameterDict[kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey]];
    } else if (urlParameterDict[@"ui_auid"]) {
      // Anonymous upgrade
      [self handleAnonymousUpgrade:urlParameterDict[@"ui_auid"]
                             email:localParameterDict[kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey]];
    } else {
      // Normal email link sign in
      [self handleEmaiLinkSignIn:localParameterDict[kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey]];
    }
  } else {
    // Different device
    if ([urlParameterDict[@"ui_sd"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
      // Force same device enabled
      [self handleDifferentDevice];
    } else {
      // Force same device not enabled
      [self handleConfirmEmail];
    }
  }

  return YES;
}
```

so I don't believe that to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

**ON IOS** 
the answer is to **attempt to sign out the user before presenting the initial email sign up/in flow from FirebaseUI, so that the link that gets *sent* to their email does not contain a Anonymous UID field**

(see below for details on why this is working (for me at least))

---

**Some Details:**

I've been working on debugging this nonstop since yesterday. So, for anyone coming across this very specific issue, I want to make some more things known about the context for above:

1. The authentication actually worked fine if I deleted the account from Firebase, but only on the *first* sign in/up attempt.
2. In general, I have the user always signed in as Anonymous until they sign up (in which case I let FirebaseUI either handle the auto upgrade or the usual sign in).

The problem entered in that I made the assumption from (2) that FirebaseUI would handle the situation correctly for all authentication methods. For email link authentication, when the user initially inputs their email into the FirebaseUI flow, if they are Anonymous at the time, it will send an email link with a field/parameter that indicates their Anonymous User ID. If this field is present when the app is opened up again via a Dynamic Link, and that link received by the app is then sent to this method:

```swift
FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!.handleOpen(link, sourceApplication: bundleIdentifier)
```

what will happen is that it will try to auto upgrade the anonymous user to the email account.

Now, for the first attempt on a new account creation, this works fine. But for subsequent attempts to use the firebase ui flow to authenticate the same email, it will try to auto upgrade an anonymous user into an account that already exists or something along those lines (the specifics will probably dictate whether this is actually a FirebaseUI issue, or if it is a FirebaseAuth issue, or if it is working as intended etc etc).

Obviously, if you rely on the data attached to a specific UID, this method will not work for you, as the UID is never preserved on email auth if you sign out the user from anonymous and then create/sign in with an email account.

If you need to preserve the UID before and after Auth or you cannot sign out the user without issue, AND you HAVE to use FirebaseUI, then I would recommend preventing the user from being able to sign out after they authenticate inside your app. This is not a great solution, so removing email authentication as a provider for FirebaseUI on iOS and relying on the other authentication providers might be better temporary solution.

**All of the above are temporary solutions**

The FirebaseUI Team should already be aware of the issue via https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/741 (which I found out is actually exactly the issue I was facing, but I ignored this originally because I didn't think it was re-authentication at all). Hopefully they will be able to make some more headway on a fix for this issue soon. If I had any idea of how best to fix this inside their flow, I would make a PR myself, but since I don't I'm going to just rely on this and wait.

---

**What about *shouldAutoUpgradeAnonymousUsers = false*?**

Turns out, after looking at the code for FirebaseUI/Auth/FUIAuth.m, FirebaseUI/Email/FUIEmailAuth.m, and FirebaseUI/Email/FUIEmailEntryViewController.m, setting this flag to false during this entire process (sign up/in, send link, open link, handle link), will not change anything. If anything it will cause the entire flow to always fail. Since the user is anonymous on the initial email link send, it will still include the anonymous uid in the link, which in turn will cause the method that handles the url to run the method that handles upgrading of the anonymous user (since there is one that appears to "need" to be upgraded).

FUIEmailAuth.m

```c
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)URL sourceApplication:(nullable NSString *)sourceApplication {

...

 } else if (urlParameterDict[@"ui_auid"]) {
   [seld handleAnonymousUpgrade:urlParameterDict[@"ui_auid"] email:localParameterDict[kEmailLinkSignInEmailKey]];
 } else {

...

}
```

That method that handles that will then skip on the initial check because we are not upgrading anonymous users, which then tries to handle the situation as if the user opened the link on a different device (incorrect, at least in this case). Which simply doesn't let the user sign in.

FUIEmailAuth.m

```c
- (void)handleAnonymousUpgrade:(NSString *)anonymousUserID email:(NSString *)email {
  // Check for the presence of an anonymous user and whether automatic upgrade is enabled.
  if (self.authUI.auth.currentUser.isAnonymous &&
      self.authUI.shouldAutoUpgradeAnonymousUsers &&
      [anonymousUserID isEqualToString:self.authUI.auth.currentUser.uid]) {

  ...

  } else {
    [self handleDifferentDevice];
  }
```